# Is it possible to file / folder or hide / archive a branch in Bitbucket, but still have the option to bring it back later if required?

Tags: bitbucket

**Short Question**

Is it possible to file / folder or hide / archive a branch in BitBucket, but still have the option to bring it back later if required?

**Long Question**

I've got a BitBucket git repo I'm working in as part of a small team of 3 developers. Our current git workflow is to create a new branch for a new feature, work on it in there, then merge to master. This works fine, but after a year of development we have ~50 branches, which is becoming quite a pain to scroll through when trying to find the right one.

Because some of these features have been shipped long ago and are pretty stable we don't require the branches anymore, although it would be nice to have a record of them in terms of what code we wrote, what didn't work, what we've already tried, etc., in case we need to re-visit the feature later.

Is it possible to hide / archive a branch in BitBucket, but still have the option to bring it back later if required?

Comment: I think this is in fact on-topic here.  Bitbucket has a web interface just like GitHub.  Can you clarify whether this is the way you are accessing the program and not through a self-hosted repo?

Comment: @jonsca im accessing the bitbucket through their web app

Comment: I'd like to know this as well. Sometimes the main interface can be cluttered by too many branches. but you want to keep certain branches archived or some 'play branches' that you didnt fork locally put somewhere. or maybe just organization with folders where you have a archive/ folder and maybe other usefully named folders like tags/ releases/ experimental-playground/ etc (which looks like has been voted alot for and no updates on: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/2323/create-a-way-to-group-repositories)